# How to toast message display when we prevent from screen shot

Tags: android

I want to display toast message "cant capture screen shot"

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: If you use FLAG_SECURE, the Notification will be `Can’t take screenshot`.